# How to get innerText (selected text not the value) from TextField as select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using material-ui for my project and I have a need to get the selected text (not the value) and do some parsing. I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Here is what my component looks like:

```
                    <TextField
                        select
                        margin="dense"
                        label="Name"
                        variant="outlined"
                        className={classes.textField}
                        value={values.nameId}
                        onChange={handleChange('nameId')}
                    >
                        {names.map(row => (
                            <MenuItem key={row.Id} value={row.Id}>{row.Name}</MenuItem>
                        ))}
                    </TextField>
```

handler looks like this:

```
const handleChange = name => event => {

    setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
};
```

Obviously event.target.value gets my selected value, but I want to also get the selected innerText of the selected index.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `event.target.innerText`?  The `target` prop of the event should contain the data for the entire element which you can access in your change handler.

Answer (score 0):

In handleChange, use Array.find() to search for the desired element, and than extract it's name:

```
 const handleChange = name => event => {
    const innerText = names
    .find(name => name.Id === event.target.value)
    .Name;

    console.log('inner text: ', innerText);

    setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
  };
```

You can check working example at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-fzquw?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 0):

I did more poking around and was able to get to the inner text using the following property:

`event._targetInst.child.alternate.memoizedProps[0]`

`event.target.innerText` does not work for material-ui `<TextField>` component. Might work for native select component however.

I am not sure if this is the best approach but it seems to work for now.